# How to detect LMB clicks?

Tags: scripting

I need to call a function when LMB is clicked somewhere in the Image Editor and I don't know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Modal operator and set your code to run on `event.type='LEFTMOUSE`'.

You can search for it on google or read this forum answers https://blenderartists.org/t/trigger-action-through-mouseclick/674367

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works as I need it to :D